# Run an existing CLI program on a web page

Tags: php, apache

This must be a solved problem, but Googling hasn't found me an answer.

I have an existing program with an interactive, text-only, command-line interface.  I'd like to run this program on a web server so that each session gets a unique session of the CLI program, and each time a command is typed into the web page the corresponding response gets sent back.

I sorta-kinda know how to do this if the program were run fresh each time; what I'm looking for is how to do this so that the program keeps running (presumably in its own process), and the web page gets updates.

It'll be on a Linux box.  Security hints would be helpful -- I'm hoping that I can run the program itself as a user that's tailored to have just enough privileges to actually run, but as little as possible otherwise to keep a hacker from getting in.

Comment: You should look into using containers, this is easily done with LXC, you could spawn a new container each time and hook into it over websockets. each container is isolated from the host and other containers.

Comment: Most PHP applications (since you've tagged this PHP) shouldn't be launched as an ongoing thing, which it seems you'd want with an application running in the background. Remember that PHP is "make connection, get answer". Eg. when would you remove their connection to the program and reset their session? Would any connection failure immediately shut down their session and their progress or would you run programs for a long time in hopes that the user is ever coming back?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to tag the post with.  I'm used to embedded programming, where a Really Fancy UI has TWO buttons.  But yes, if it's on something that's of the "make connection, get answer" sort then I'd want the first connection of the session to spin off the application as a deamon, or in the background or some such, and then each access talks to the same running app (keeping track of which web session belongs to which app instance by magic, until I understand it).

Answer (score 2):

Try https://seashells.io/

Seashells lets you pipe output from command-line programs to the web in real-time, even without installing any new software on your machine. You can use it to monitor long-running processes like experiments that print progress to the console. You can also use Seashells to share output with friends!

```
$ echo 'Hello, Seashells!' | nc seashells.io 1337
serving at https://seashells.io/v/{random url}
```

Other article explaining [seashells](https://www.ostechnix.com/seashells-pipe-linux-commands-output-web-real-time/)

Another alternative if you only want to see the result of the command, you can use [websocketd](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

https://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/

Then, you'd need to configure a user with limited rights that automatically launches the desired application. Make sure you understand Linux security before you do this. :)

Here is some information on restricting SSH sessions that you may find useful for this objective:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8257

Comment: Hmm.  Seems a bit TOO plain -- I was more looking for something that'd run in an area of the web page, with static stuff scattered around it.  But I'll look into it.

Comment: Any thoughts on a similar app designed to put the shell into a frame within a web page?  So I can scatter look & feel around the thing, but still have my shell inside?

Comment: That may be possible with this one. We'd need to get access to a working installation of it and see how it draws the page. I looked around for a publicly accessible installation, but did not have success.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/shellinabox/issues/253. - it appears possible to put the shell in an iframe, which would permit arbitrary styling around it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least a partial answer is just basic Linux-ness: I stumbled across named pipes (which I *knew about*, dangit!).  After testing, I can set up a pair of pipes, and then run my command as

```
tail -f in_pipe.fifo | my_command > out_pipe.fifo
```

Then the transient commands will just need to open the relevant pipes, talk to them, close, and exit.  I'll still need to manage the lifetime of the above command (no doubt timers will be involved, and magic), but that's a question for another posting.

At this point I can open three terminal windows: one with the above command running, one with `tail -f out_pipe.fifo` running, and one in which I type things of the form `echo line of input > in_pipe.fifo`, and it all works.  I'm sure that (A) I can work this out from here, and (B) it'll be ugly.

I did have to get into the source code for the program and make sure that the output buffer was flushed (using fflush(stdout)) in the C-code.  (I'm working from some vintage source code; at this point I'm trying to do the minimal amount of work to make it compile and run -- every line changed is an opportunity for a bug, and I'm not yet familiar with this code base).